# QML Rectangle as an Icon for a toolbox in Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have designed an Image using Rectangle in QML in the Qt platform. I would like to take this QML file and add it on to my other Project in Visual Studio with Qt.

I have added my QML file in the resources of my Qt project in Visual Studio and have used the following code but gives me several external unresolved errors.

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
view->setSource(QUrl("main.qml"));
```

I would be glad if someone could help me out in using this QML Image as an Icon to the toolBox.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: __cdecl QQuickView::QQuickView(class QWindow *)"
>   (__imp_??0QQuickView@@QEAA@PEAVQWindow@@@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: __cdecl QtGuiApplication1::QtGuiApplication1(class QWidget
>   *)" (??0QtGuiApplication1@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)  QtGuiApplication1   C:\Users\Desktop\QtGuiApplication1\QtGuiApplicatio
>   n1\QtGuiApplication1.obj  1    Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl
>   QQuickView::~QQuickView(void)" (__imp_??1QQuickView@@UEAA@XZ)
>   referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl
>   QQuickView::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)"
>   (??_GQQuickView@@UEAAPEAXI@Z) QtGuiApplication1
>   C:\Users\Desktop\QtGuiApplication1\QtGuiApplicatio
>   n1\QtGuiApplication1.obj  1    Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl
>   QQuickView::setSource(class QUrl const &)"
>   (__imp_?setSource@QQuickView@@QEAAXAEBVQUrl@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: __cdecl QtGuiApplication1::QtGuiApplication1(class
>   QWidget *)"
>   (??0QtGuiApplication1@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)  QtGuiApplication1   C:\Users\Desktop\QtGuiApplication1\QtGuiApplicatio
>   n1\QtGuiApplication1.obj  1    Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   "public: virtual class QAccessibleInterface * __cdecl
>   QQuickWindow::accessibleRoot(void)const "
>   (?accessibleRoot@QQuickWindow@@UEBAPEAVQAccessible
>   Interface@@XZ)    QtGuiApplication1   C:\Users\Desktop\QtGuiApplication1\QtGuiApplicatio
>   n1\QtGuiApplication1.obj  1

I am using Visual Studio with Qt and I think I need not add anything to .pro file.

Comment: I need not do that I guess as I am using Qt with Visual studio

Comment: You may need to link to Qt5Quick.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, .... (Note that I'm not very familiar with the combination of Visual Studio and Qt)

Comment: You may need to add CONFIG += quick to the .pro, if it's not already there, and what @m7913d said.